# Error in position_stack(vjust=0.5) : unused argument (vjust = 0.5)

Tags: r

Trying to position labels in the middle of stacked bar chart bars with this as the code:

```
(p <- ggplot(colsDF, aes(x, y, fill = z, label=y)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(size=3, position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
)
```

But I get the error in the title:

```
Error in position_stack(vjust=0.5) : unused argument (vjust = 0.5)
```

I've tried using margin and height and other things I've found online with position_stack but keep getting the same error.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images, so we can copy/paste and help debug it.

Comment: Very small coding section I'm focusing on cause seems like the dataset and variables don't really matter. I just added it in as code.

Answer (score 0):

`vjust` should be outside:

```
 geom_text(size=3, position=position_stack(),vjust=0.5)
```

Comment: My impression of putting it in the position_stack brackets was that it was supposed to put it in the centre of the bar part, if i put it outside it just moves it down a bit regardless of the bar section its in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem when I go from a local machine to deployment of a shiny app on a Shiny Server.

It looks like the issue is due to the version of ggplot2. Based upon comparing the documentation, the function:

```
position_stack(vjust = 1.0, reverse = FALSE)
```

is new in ggplot2 version 2.2.0+.

If you're able, try updating to the newest ggplot2 release from CRAN.